# How to print a float number without extra zero digits in C

Tags: c, digits

When I print a float number with "%f", it prints a float with 6 digits, but I don't want to print extra zeros. I can to use for example "%.3f" to print just 3 digits, but I want to print a float with number of random digits ,and using "%.{number}f" is not my answer. for example in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a, b;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Please enter another number: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("%f", a / b);
    return 0;
}
```

a/b can have even decimal digits. Of course, my question also applies to double and long double too.

Comment: Can you give an example for what you try to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: Use `"%g"` (or `"%lg"`) which will only print the needed number of digits. (e.g. for `1.0` it will only output `1`, for `1.25` it will output `1.25`)

Comment: @Weather Vane why are you recommending `sprintf()` instead of `snprintf()`?

Comment: @Weather Vane The OP is obviously a beginner, and you probably shouldn't recommend such practice to beginners, because sooner or later they are going to make the mistake of using it when not appropriate.

Comment: @DarkAtom. So why are recommending not checking the return value from `scanf()` in your code?

Comment: Because the OP is also not doing it. Checking against buffer overflows is much more important then checking for validity of the input in toy programs.

Comment: @DarkAtom please set a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to remove the extra zeros.

1. Easiest way is to use `%g` as the format specifier in the `printf` statement. Eg. `printf("%g",a/b);`. This is remove the extra zeros after the decimal.
2. You can use `printf("%.0d%.4g\n", (int)(a/b)/10, (a/b)-((int)(a/b)-(int)(a/b)%10));`.
3. You can use a separate function to remove the extra zeros but it is a tedious process. First transfer all the digits to a string and remove the unwanted zeros from the end.
4. You can also use `%.2f` format specifier to reduce the zeros. Eg. `printf("%.2f",a/b);` - this can be used where you want to print the exact number of digits after the decimal point. `%.<the number of digits to be printed after decimal point>f`.

Comment: 1 and 3 are good ideas.  2 is prone to failure: 1) when `a/b` outside `int` range, 2) the rounded FP math rounds unexpectedly as with 0.9999999999.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code to print n non-zero decimal digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    float a, b;
    scanf("%f %f %d", &a, &b, &n);
    float result = a / b;
    printf("%d", (int)result);
    int decimal = (int)trunc(result * pow(10, n)) % (int)pow(10, n);
    if (decimal != 0)
        while (decimal % 10 == 0)
            decimal /= 10;
    printf(".%d\n", decimal);
}
```